# Docker incremental build does not reuse cache

Tags: docker, maven

I am trying to build a huge docker image in an optimized way by applying the principles of incremental building explained here https://www.docker.com/blog/intro-guide-to-dockerfile-best-practices/ .

Unfortunately each time I run the build command docker restarts building the image from scratch, and so I have to download again all the maven dependencies.

Here is the build command:

```sh
docker build \
    --build-arg MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE="${HOME}/.m2/settings.xml" \
    --build-arg PROJECT_PATH="." \
    --file "${DOCKER_FILE}" \
    --tag "${IMAGE_TAG}" \
    .
```

and here te `Dockerfile`:

```
# Global vars (for passing between stages)

ARG MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE
ARG PROJECT_PATH

ARG APP_FOLDER=/app

# 1st stage

FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11 as build

# Build artifact

ARG APP_FOLDER
ENV APP_FOLDER ${APP_FOLDER}

ARG MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE
ENV MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE}

ARG PROJECT_PATH
ENV PROJECT_PATH ${PROJECT_PATH}

WORKDIR ${APP_FOLDER}

ADD ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE} .

ADD ${PROJECT_PATH}/pom.xml .
RUN mvn package -s ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE} -DskipTests

ADD ${PROJECT_PATH}/src src
RUN mvn package -s ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE} -DskipTests

# 2nd stage: build image

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

ARG APP_FOLDER
ENV APP_FOLDER ${APP_FOLDER}

ENV TARGET_FOLDER ${APP_FOLDER}/target

WORKDIR ${APP_FOLDER}

# Copy the binary built in the 1st stage

COPY --from=build ${TARGET_FOLDER}/myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Thank you so much for any suggestion!

---

### **Edit 1 (for @sai)**

Hi @sai, I checked the cached layers by `docker history` command and I observed that the MVN steps are missing!

```sh
IMAGE          CREATED          CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
b78b3d09d314   16 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["java" "-Doracle.jdb…   0B        
a2db7da187f0   16 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 8080                  0B        
ed8f3dc45017   16 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 8081                  0B        
715f12eba281   16 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:33e2303bf32b392fc…   58.3MB    
4edb35a1b6f6   16 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:0b42aca8bb0ad316…   234kB     
56ecbfb34e74   16 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:8497884af419f408f…   4.59kB    
255913b0fc25   16 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /app                  0B        
87c5b4ca34df   16 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV TARGET_FOLDER=/app/ta…   0B        
5f95ab5b8d19   16 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV APP_FOLDER=/app          0B        
da6d51b1d3b8   16 minutes ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG APP_FOLDER               0B        
940f48bb6c92   3 days ago       /bin/sh -c set -eux;   arch="$(dpkg --print-…   142MB     
<missing>      3 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_VERSION=11.0.11+9   0B        
<missing>      3 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=C.UTF-8             0B        
<missing>      3 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/local/openj…   0B        
<missing>      3 days ago       /bin/sh -c { echo '#/bin/sh'; echo 'echo "$J…   27B       
<missing>      3 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/…   0B        
<missing>      3 days ago       /bin/sh -c set -eux;  apt-get update;  apt-g…   8.82MB    
<missing>      3 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B        
<missing>      3 days ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:7362e0e50f30ff454…   69.3MB
```

My opinion is that all the instructions which use a variable to be expanded do not generate a cached layer. Is it right for you too?

---

### **Edit 2 (Helidon demo)**

I tryed to go digger with Helidon demo, and I observed that it does not show in the history the MVN layer. Conversely it uses cached layers.

Look at the docker file and second build execution log:

```
# 1st stage, build the app
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11 as build

WORKDIR /helidon

# Create a first layer to cache the "Maven World" in the local repository.
# Incremental docker builds will always resume after that, unless you update
# the pom
ADD pom.xml .
RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip -Declipselink.weave.skip

# Do the Maven build!
# Incremental docker builds will resume here when you change sources
ADD src src
RUN mvn package -DskipTests
RUN echo "done!"

# 2nd stage, build the runtime image
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
WORKDIR /helidon

# Copy the binary built in the 1st stage
COPY --from=build /helidon/target/helidon-quickstart-mp.jar ./
COPY --from=build /helidon/target/libs ./libs

CMD ["java", "-jar", "helidon-quickstart-mp.jar"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

```sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon  43.01kB
Step 1/13 : FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11 as build
 ---> e23b595c92ad
Step 2/13 : WORKDIR /helidon
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 25e45ff1f01d
Step 3/13 : ADD pom.xml .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ec5c0a3ecd2c
Step 4/13 : RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip -Declipselink.weave.skip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a21083c406a0
Step 5/13 : ADD src src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d718f90a4c6d
Step 6/13 : RUN mvn package -DskipTests
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ebdb2ff847fd
Step 7/13 : RUN echo "done!"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d9c9f46d0af2
Step 8/13 : FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
 ---> 940f48bb6c92
Step 9/13 : WORKDIR /helidon
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e0aa150de7c3
Step 10/13 : COPY --from=build /helidon/target/helidon-quickstart-mp.jar ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0f64c021b20f
Step 11/13 : COPY --from=build /helidon/target/libs ./libs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d2c6fad54ac1
Step 12/13 : CMD ["java", "-jar", "helidon-quickstart-mp.jar"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7de63ada236c
Step 13/13 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d6a11cd62373
Successfully built d6a11cd62373
Successfully tagged helidon-quickstart-mp:latest
```

---

### **Edit 3 (issue reason found)

I looked better at my second build execution log and I supposed, the ENV variabiles assignments breaking the caching:

```sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.294MB

Step 1/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_BUILD_FULL_VERSION
Step 2/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_BUILD_PROFILE
Step 3/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_BUILD_VERSION
Step 4/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_BUILD_OPTIONS
Step 5/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_POM_ARTIFACT_ID
Step 6/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_POM_GROUP_ID
Step 7/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_POM_VERSION
Step 8/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE
Step 9/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_PROJECT_PATH
Step 10/36 : ARG APP_FOLDER=/app
Step 11/36 : FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11 as build
 ---> e23b595c92ad
Step 12/36 : ARG APP_FOLDER
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7418c1e78088
Step 13/36 : ENV APP_FOLDER ${APP_FOLDER}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9fb55b74b57b
Step 14/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9de7642ea7ae
Step 15/36 : ENV CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE ${CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE}
 ---> Running in 0d5655b4dd2b
Removing intermediate container 0d5655b4dd2b
 ---> d590a3bc4167
Step 16/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_BUILD_OPTIONS
 ---> Running in 528c5d6c82f2
Removing intermediate container 528c5d6c82f2
 ---> 5ec69a0c4629
Step 17/36 : ENV CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_BUILD_OPTIONS ${CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_BUILD_OPTIONS}
 ---> Running in eefe59ddc94b
Removing intermediate container eefe59ddc94b
 ---> beb77c7c67e5
Step 18/36 : ARG CI_CONTAINER_PROJECT_PATH
 ---> Running in da389f2e0824
Removing intermediate container da389f2e0824
 ---> 6835d33be70e
Step 19/36 : ENV CI_CONTAINER_PROJECT_PATH ${CI_CONTAINER_PROJECT_PATH}
 ---> Running in 89420b67a110
Removing intermediate container 89420b67a110
 ---> fd1b05ed1dfd
Step 20/36 : WORKDIR ${APP_FOLDER}
 ---> Running in 39135509f1d7
Removing intermediate container 39135509f1d7
 ---> 833258753a45
Step 21/36 : COPY ${CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE} .
 ---> 6f1b6a7176de
Step 22/36 : COPY ${CI_CONTAINER_PROJECT_PATH}/pom.xml .
 ---> 92f34751c641
Step 23/36 : RUN mvn -e -B -s ${CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE} -DskipTests -Dmaven.openapi-generator.skip ${CI_CONTAINER_MAVEN_BUILD_OPTIONS} package
 ---> Running in 38fcf8af4523
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading from public: http://ci.betting.sisal.it/nexus/repository/maven-public/it/sisal/betting/root-pom/2.0.2/root-pom-2.0.2.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from public: http://ci.betting.sisal.it/nexus/repository/maven-public/it/sisal/betting/root-pom/2.0.2/root-pom-2.0.2.pom (12 kB at 41 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloading from public: http://ci.betting.sisal.it/nexus/repository/maven-public/io/helidon/helidon-dependencies/2.3.0/helidon-dependencies-2.3.0.pom

... and so on...
```

**Now I should know to make variable assignments cacheable!!!**

Comment: Which step doesn't get cached?  (The very first `RUN mvn package`?)  Are all of the `ARG` values and the contents of the Maven settings files identical across rebuilds?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze! Yes, the not cached step is the first MVN invoke, and as you can see in the build command, the arguments don't change.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca the logs do not match the build command or Dockerfile provided, and the output indicates that the args are changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found the solution!**

The first problem was related to a detail of my build command that I did not show in the original post: the `MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE` was generated by the `mktemp` so it used to change at any execution, consequently invalidating the following layers.

The second issue was that I did not really need the ENV variables, but the ARGs were enough.

So, I rewritten them as follow, and all the layers are reused from cache as expected.

```sh
M2_SETTINGS_FILE=.settings.xml
cp "${HOME}/.m2/settings.xml" "${M2_SETTINGS_FILE}"

docker build \
    --build-arg MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE="${M2_SETTINGS_FILE}" \
    --build-arg PROJECT_PATH="." \
    --file "${DOCKER_FILE}" \
    --tag "${IMAGE_TAG}" \
    .
```

```
# Global vars (for passing between stages)

ARG MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE
ARG PROJECT_PATH

ARG APP_FOLDER=/app

# 1st stage

FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11 as build

# Build artifact

ARG APP_FOLDER
ARG MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE
ARG PROJECT_PATH

WORKDIR ${APP_FOLDER}

ADD ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE} .
ADD ${PROJECT_PATH}/pom.xml .
RUN mvn package -s ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE} -DskipTests

ADD ${PROJECT_PATH}/src src
RUN mvn package -s ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE} -DskipTests

# 2nd stage: build image

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

ARG APP_FOLDER
ARG TARGET_FOLDER ${APP_FOLDER}/target

WORKDIR ${APP_FOLDER}

# Copy the binary built in the 1st stage

COPY --from=build ${TARGET_FOLDER}/myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds) it is mentioned that

> Each FROM instruction can use a different base, and each of them begins a new stage of the build

To check what steps are cached, run the following command

```
docker history <IMAGE_NAME>
```

You will only see the instructions from the final build.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @sai, what you explained is not properly right. I am developing a Helidon application, and if you follow the tutorial at https://helidon.io/docs/latest/#/mp/guides/10_mp-tutorial you will can see that the Dockerfile generated by the maven artifact template is similar to mine, but if we change something in the source code, only the 2nd MVN instruction is invoked, and the 1st one, which downloaded all the dependecies, is never called, as expected.

Comment: Hi @antonio-petricca, In multi-stages the final build will be tagged with docker image name which you gave them. However, the intermediate builds could be present in the system as dangling images (image with <none> as its name) which can be used as cache, instead of building the entire image agin. Just check if dangling images are created while you build your Dockerfile. To check for the dangling images present in the system, use the following command `docker images  -f dangling=true`

Comment: I edited the main post adding **Edit 2 (for @sai)**.

Comment: In the **Edit 3** I demostrated that variable assignments break layers caching! :(

Comment: Yeah, this is just wrong. Well, it's right that from builds a new stage, but it's wrong in the context of the question -- each of the separate layers is still cached.

Comment: Solution found, and detailed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67556232/418599